# Error: Stream error in the HTTP/2 framing layer

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, api

I am working on my Graduation Project. We make our database using Laravel And MYSQL, then we made The API for the mobile app and uploaded it on 000webhost to use it online.

Before uploaded, we tried every single method on INSOMNIA locally and works fine,
but when we try it online only GET and POST methods work and when we try to use DELETE method we get this error `Error: Stream error in the HTTP/2 framing layer`.

Can you help us please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's not enough information in your question so I'd recommend reading [asking instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with the emphasis on the part about [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

000webhost does not allow any other HTTP method except **GET**, **POST**, and **HEAD**.

So, Instead of a FREE plan, you will have to choose a PAID plan for use all HTTP methods.